# Heroku BeautifulSoup + cloudscraper don't bypass cloudflare on server side

Tags: python, heroku, beautifulsoup

i'm using [BeautifulSoup](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/) + [cloudscraper](https://pythonrepo.com/repo/VeNoMouS-cloudscraper-python-web-crawling) to scrap a site. The problem is in local it's working but on heroku server it doesn't work.

It's look like when i launch the script via heroku server the JS or cookie are not enable. That why in local cloudscraper can bypass cloudflare and not on heroku.

My code:

```
 import requests
 import cloudscraper
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

 session = requests.session()
 scraper = cloudscraper.create_scraper(browser='chrome', sess=session)
 contract_page = scraper.get("https://bscscan.com/token/0x30e650783b4046c64dcf3b7b78854f3d4a87b058",
        headers = {
            'user-agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.81 Safari/537.36",
            'Cache-Control': "no-cache",
        })
  soupa = BeautifulSoup(contract_page.content, 'html.parser')
  print(soupa)
  tokenholders = soupa.find(id='ContentPlaceHolder1_tr_tokenHolders').get_text()
```

the print of soupa give me this HTML page:
[image]

Someone have idea how to enable JS or cookie from a heroku server that run the script please ?

Comment: `bs4` can't run `JS` so you either need `selenium` and a browser driver or `requests-html`.

Comment: It's working on my local env ...

Comment: Then they're probably blocking heroku's IP's

Answer (score 0):

After many tried i found a solution, to bypass it we have to use a proxy to change the IP of heroku server.